# Prove that there is a sequence of complex polynomials $P_n:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $P_n(a_n)=n+1$

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

> Consider the sequence $a_n=(1/n)e^{i/(n+1)}$ and the sets $K_n=\{z\in \bar{D}(0,n):1/n\leq \arg z\leq 2\pi\}\cup \{0\}$. Prove that there is a sequence of complex polynomials $P_n:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $P_n(a_n)=n+1$ and $\|P_n\|_{K_n}<1/2$.

So I was going to use the following consequence of Runge's Theorem:

If $K\subset \mathbb{C}$ is compact and $\mathbb{C}-K$ is connected then any holomorphic map on a neighborhood of $K$ can be approximated uniformly on $K$ by polynomials.

If I use it I can show the statement $\|P_n\|_{K_n}<1/2$ easily. But how do I know or make them so that $P_n(a_n)=n+1$?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For each $n$ we can choose disjoint open discs $D_1,D_2$ containing $K_n$ and $\{a_n\}$ respectively. The function that is $0$ on $D_1$ and $n+1$ on $D_2$ is holomorphic on $D_1 \cup D_2.$

Comment: But how do we know that $a_n$'s are in $D_2$?

Comment: There was a typo and I just corrected it.

Comment: Ok, but I am still having a problem. Now what we can say is $|P_n(a_n)-(n+1)|<\epsilon$. How do you say $P_n(a_n)$ is exactly $n+1$?

Comment: How about defining $Q_n =[(n+1)/P_n(a_n)]P_n?$

Comment: You mean multiply $P_n(z)$ by $(n+1)/P_n(a_n)$ and take that new polynomial as my $P_n(z)$?

Comment: Probably better to name the first polynomial $Q_n,$ the second polynomial $P_n.$

Comment: OOps, i got one more question. How do you say that $a_n\notin K_n$? Is it a typo that $a_n=(1/n)e^{1/(n+1)}$, and should it be $(1/n)e^{i/(n+1)}$?

Comment: @Derivative $a_n > 1/n.$

Comment: Sorry my mistake. $K_n$'s were wrong. Please see my edit.

Comment: That can't be right for obvious reasons.

Comment: What reasons? I am confused. I think $K_n$'s are now correct, but $a_n$'s should be $(1/n)e^{i/(n+1)}$

Comment: I actually want my $K_n$'s so that they cover entire complex plane as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: With this definition of $K_n,$ we have $a_n \in K_n.$